# How do I configure allocationSize within persistence.xml instead of Entity

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

Is there any possibility to do a kind of "refactor" of **allocationSize** in order to put it inside the perssitence.xml instead of having to configure it inside each Entity ?

here's what I don't want to have :

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="AGENT_IDAGENT_GENERATOR", sequenceName="AGENT_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
```

here's what I'm expecting to have

```
    <properties>
        <property name="allocationSize" value="1"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SessionCustomizer in your persistence.xml, iterate over the Session's login's Sequence objects and set their preallocation size.

An allocation size of 1, it not recommended, it will have poor performance, you may be better off with the default.

Comment: Agreed about the allocationSize=1. However, maybe the OP must not have a non-continuous IDs? Can't the 'holes' in IDs occur if the server crashes after allocation of some ID blocks? And by the way what is a SessionCustomizer? Is this some Eclipselink specific feature?

Comment: Yes, SessionCustomizer is specific to EclipseLink, it gives access to the API and advanced functionality

Answer (score 1):

If wanting a JPA solution, then you can't put it in *persistence.xml*, just use *orm.xml*

Comment: But then again - if every entity have a separate SequenceGenerator, the 'allocationSize=1' must occur in every SequenceGenerator element in orm.xml, right? There is no 'override default value of 50 for allocationSize' for all sequence generators?

Comment: Of course, each is specified individually; there is no "persistence-unit-default" for that attribute, as per the JPA spec. JPA implementations themselves usually provide global defaults, DataNucleus does certainly; but we always encourage sticking to the spec.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification @DataNucleus; I just thought that the OP was asking for one-for-all solution.