# JPA Table Strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

While using the JPA tablegeneration strategy , we need to mention the allocation size in the @TableGenerator.
The default value is 50. We want to override the default allocation size.

But the allocation size needs to be mentioned in every entity. 
Is there any other better way of doing this ( like configuring it globally or by configuring it as an additional column in the table used for tracking generated Ids )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Plain JPA this does not seem to be possible as noted in these posts:

[Setting default allocation size for all entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667638/setting-default-allocation-size-for-all-entities)

[How do I configure allocationSize within persistence.xml instead of Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927826/how-do-i-configure-allocationsize-within-persistence-xml-instead-of-entity)

It appears that the `EclipseLink` JPA implementation does provide you with the ability to set this element globally with the `SessionCustomizer'

Comment: Thanks . We are using hibernate . Is the configuration possible using hibernate ?

Comment: I searched for information on Hibernate and didn't find anything.  Doesn't mean its not out there, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: extending annotations is not supported. Otherwise we can extend the TableGenerator annotation and override the default value i.e. 50.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using hibernate @genericgenerator. we can override the allocation size by fetching it from table and then reconfiguring the idgenerator